# Can only change font-family of text with jQuery once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble changing the font-family of my text with jQuery.

My html:

```
<select id="message-font-selection" class="promo">
                        <option value="Oswald">Oswald</option>
                        <option value="Open Sans">Open Sans</option>
                        <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                        <option value="Indie Flower">Indie Flower</option>
                        <option value="Poiret One">Poiret One</option>
                    </select>


<div class="middle-section">{{middle_msg}}</div>
```

My js:

```
$('#message-font-selection').change(function() {
    $('.middle-section').css('font-family',$(this).val());
});
```

The problem is that I can only change the font once. However, when I try selecting a different font-family for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc... time, the font no longer visibly changes. However, when I inspect the element, I can see that the font-family style for that text is indeed being changed... but those changes are not reflected on the screen...
I have basically the same exact code for font-color and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Can you create https://jsfiddle.net/ for your issue Or add snippet here to understand properly your issue

Comment: Is it happening for all fonts? It sounds like may be fonts are not included in your css?

Comment: I iterated through all fonts. They all work as expected when they are the first font to be selected.

Comment: Its working if I use css font-family..see Demo https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/ha37efLr/1/..I don't know which file do u included for font..May b it doesnot loaded properly

Comment: it seems the font family which is loaded does not exists on your machine.

Comment: adding js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/shahamitr/wda3w657/#&togetherjs=djrELF8lom

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the use of "this":

```
$(document).on('change', $('#message-font-selection'), function() {
   alert('The value of $(this).val() is: ' + $(this).val() );
   $('.middle-section').css('font-family',$('#message-font-selection').val());
});
```

As you can see, replacing "$(this).val()" with a reference to the actual element fixes the issue.

Also, by using $(document).on listener, you can listen for a change in the element even if it doesn't exist when the listener is registered.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/jvk0t2x8/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at code,

it is working when i tried with the basic fonts which are available globally,

```
<select id="message-font-selection" class="promo">
                        <option value="arial">arial</option>
                        <option value="times new roman">times new roman</option>
                        <option value="calibri">calibri</option>
                    </select><br><br><br><br>
<div class="middle-section">This is test</div>


$('#message-font-selection').change(function() {
    $('.middle-section').css('font-family',$(this).val());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems to fix the problem. I will go with globally available fonts for now. However I am confused as to why the first font change correctly updates the font-family and subsequent ones do not.

Comment: @vgbcell gr8, to use extra ordinary fonts you need to first import it or load it on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code with little modification(**Change on font name**) and it's working fine.

```
<select id="message-font-selection" class="promo">
            <option value="Oswald">Oswald</option>
            <option value="fantasy">fantasy</option>
            <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
            <option value="cursive">cursive</option>
            <option value="Poiret One">Poiret One</option>
        </select>

        <div class="middle-section">Test</div>
```

JS

```
     $('#message-font-selection').change(function() {
    $('.middle-section').css('font-family',$(this).val());
    });
```